# heroku can't start nodejs app

Tags: node.js, heroku, port

my app works fine local. But when I upload it to github and try to start it with heroku, it says "application error". The build log doesn't show any errors but the app log shows this:[image: app log]
and I think I my port connection is right:

```
const config = {
 port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
};
app.listen(config.port);
```

package.json:

```
{
 "name": "labo4",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "nodemon ."
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
  "ejs": "^2.5.7",
  "express": "^4.16.3",
  "glob": "^7.1.2",
  "jade": "^1.11.0",
  "path": "^0.12.7"
 }
}
```

Comment: share your `package.json` please

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya I added my package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**package.json**

```
{
 "name": "labo4",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
  "ejs": "^2.5.7",
  "express": "^4.16.3",
  "glob": "^7.1.2",
  "jade": "^1.11.0",
  "path": "^0.12.7"
 }
}
```

By default Heroku will search for a start in your `package.json` so edit it as above.